# Serializable with inheritance

Tags: java, serialization

`BB` is the parent to `B`. `A` is a stand-alone class. All I'm doing with this code is writing an object of type `B` to a file and then reading it back.

The code as shown runs okay. Additionally, we know that if a class is `Serializable` then its subclasses are automatically `Serializable` too.

With that in mind, why do I get a `NotSerializableException` if instead of B being serializable, BB (its parent) is? I would expect the same output in both cases.

```
 public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            B bb = new B();
            B bb2 = null;
            try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("text.ser"));
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("text.ser"))){
                oos.writeObject(bb);
                bb2 = (B) ois.readObject();
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }

    class A {
        int a = 1, hello=7;
        A() {a = 2;}
        }

    class BB {
        int bb = 1;
        A aInstance = new A();
        BB() {bb = 2;}
    }

    class B extends BB implements Serializable{
        int b = 1;
        B() {b = 2;}
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BB` has a field of type `A`, and `A` does not implement `Serializable`. In a serializable class, the types of all fields must be serializable, as must the types of the fields of those types, and so on.

---

Alternatively (although you probably don't want this), you can use the `transient` keyword to declare the field to be excluded from serialization:

```
transient A aInstance = new A();
```

If you do this, `aInstance` will be `null` when a `B` or `BB` instance is deserialized, even if the field was non-`null` when the instance was serialized.